# ios UIImage:imageWithContentsOfFile struck

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

here i am download the image from url and saveit in to the cache directory,and we taken the image from the cached path but its strucked to get the image.is there any alternative solution to get the image from the localpath

Here i shared the code to get the image from the localpath:

```
NSString *cachePath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", cachePath,[[imageurl componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"]lastObject]];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Comment: NSLog your path and check if it is correct or not.

Comment: I dont know what "strucked" means could you provide NSLog of the cachePath and path?  And provide any exceptions.  Is image nil after the call?

Comment: Thanks for your response,i am displaying the image in the tableview,whenever the cell reused the image is taken from the localpath so that its struck to loading the images

Answer (score 0):

You should make an NSObject class that handles the downloading and caching of images. Example

Interface file

```
        #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

            @interface ImageCache : NSObject
            {
             UIImage *background;
            }
   @property (nonatomic,retain) UIImage *background;         
            -(void)getImages;
            -(void) storeImages;
            -(void) clearCache;

    @end
```

Implementation

```
    @implementation ImageCache

        @synthesize background;


            - (void) cacheImage: (NSString *) ImageURLString : (NSString *)imageName
            {
                NSURL *ImageURL = [NSURL URLWithString: ImageURLString];

                // Generate a unique path to a resource representing the image you want

                NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                NSString *docDir = [paths objectAtIndex: 0];
                NSString *docFile = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: imageName];

                // Check for file existence
                if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: docFile])
                {
                    // The file doesn't exist, we should get a copy of it

                    // Fetch image
                    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: ImageURL];

                    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData: data];

                    // Is it PNG or JPG/JPEG?
                    // Running the image representation function writes the data from the image to a file
                    if([ImageURLString rangeOfString: @".png" options: NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound)
                    {

                        [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile: docFile atomically: YES];

                    }
                    else if
                    (
                            [ImageURLString rangeOfString: @".jpg" options: NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound || 
                            [ImageURLString rangeOfString: @".jpeg" options: NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound
                    )
                    {
                        [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 100) writeToFile: docFile atomically: YES];
                    }
                }
            }

            - (UIImage *) getCachedImage : (NSString *)imageName
            {

                NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
                (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
                NSString* cachedPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];

                UIImage *image;

                // Check for a cached version
                if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: cachedPath])
                {
                    image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: cachedPath]; // this is the cached image
                }else
                {
                    NSLog(@"Error");
                }

                return image;
            }

        -(void)getImages
        {    
//I just googled background image and took first image I found for this example
         NSString *backgroundURL = @"http://www.dvd-ppt-slideshow.com/images/ppt-background/background-3.jpg";  
        [self cacheImage:backgroundURL: @"Background"];

        }

    -(void) clearCache
    {
    //If you ever need to clear the cache for whatever reason, good to have a method to handle it    
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *docDir = [paths objectAtIndex: 0];
        NSString *docFile1 = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"Background"];
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        [fileManager removeItemAtPath:docFile1 error:NULL];

    }

    -(void) storeImages
    {
        background = [self getCachedImage:@"Background"];
    }

@end
```

In example I gave I just used one image. But you get the idea I am sure. Now if you want to download and store that image. Just import the ImageCache class in your ViewController then call

```
ImageCache *cacheMe = [[ImageCache alloc] init];
   [cache getImages];
    [cacheMe storeImages];
    UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[cacheMe background]];
```

And thats all you need to do. Much easer if you have a class dedicated to caching. Hope that helps!!

Edit: Update forgot two lines of code. I tested it myself, should work fine now

Comment: thanks,actually this kind of retrieving process is only i am using.my problem is to get image from the local-path and display it in to the tableview in this getting image from the local-path is st-rucking.how can i fluently scroll the tableview could you have any idea

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you mean by stucking? Do you just want a tableview that contains different images? If so, my code should work fine. Just set up a tableview, and give each cell an image. Or if you want text and image, then you will need to create your own custom table cell